# How can I dynamically call dangerous PHP functions to develop a proof-of-concept?

Tags: php, security, penetration-testing

I am doing a white-box penetration test, and my unfamiliarity with PHP specifics is making it difficult to develop a proof-of-concept. Here is a stripped down example of a function I believe to be dangerous. (There's some validation and error-handling that I removed for simplicity's sake.)

```
function makeCall($myClass, $method, $args){
   $theClass = new $myClass();
   return $theClass->$method($args);
}
```

This issue is that all of the parameters are able to be controlled by a potential attacker through something like `site.com/program.php/class/method?args=args`. The normal usage of `makeCall` is that an some class and method made by the company are passed to the function as strings. I am able to make calls to other classes that were obviously not intended to be called, so there's definitely some issue here.

My goal is to be able to use `exec` for the `$method` param (or something similar) in order to demonstrate just how dangerous this code is - remote code execution being the objective here. I can't for the life of me figure out what "class" `exec` (or similar) would be inside of (or if that's even the right question). Is there a built-in class with a dangerous method I could use to prove my point?

For example, in C#, I could do something like `System.IO.File` for the class, and `ReadAllLines` for the method, with the args being some sensitive file on the server. I am perfectly willing to accept an answer of "this wont work for any generic php methods" but I want to be sure.

Comment: Well I guess in similar to your C# example you could look at `DomDocument` and `load`. And yes, agreed, blindly trusting a user is never a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for your comment ficuscr. It actually put me on a useful track, I think. I am going through http://php.net/manual/en/funcref.php and basically what I need is a Class that has a method that takes an object as a parameter that lets me execute code. Another way of asking my question would be... is there any class name you can put in front of a built-in function and have it still make the call. For example, if something like `self.shell_exec` would work (it doesn't). Do those built-ins have a default namespace that does not **have** to be included, but **can** be included?

Comment: There probably is an easy way to leverage this into RCE, but I can't think of any now. You could also start with something like: `ArrayObject::unserialize('[inject here]')`, and search the web for a few unserialize exploits that prove the danger (there're plenty).

Comment: Like where @jh1711is going. Question proved interesting to think about. Final thought, [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Object_Injection) is still a good resource for this topic and might give you an idea.

Comment: That's a clever idea @jh1711. Unfortunately, my param has to be a JSON string that is converted to an object before being passed to the specified function, and unserialize takes a string. I know this wasn't mentioned in the OP, but I didn't want to bog it down with too many restrictions, and there may still be a way to make that work.

Comment: @Gray no worries, your question mentioned that you removed some validation. May I ask how the JSON is converted? Normally JSON decoded input is easier to exploit, because you can pass numbers and booleans (and objects) in addition to strings and arrays.

Comment: @jh1711 So, I may have been inaccurate before. It creates a new object with the class, method, and arguments. The arguments go through a lot of stuff: `urldecode`, `serialize`, `filter_var` (with `FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS`), `html_entity_decode`, `unserialize`,  and finally `json_decode`. I am honestly a little confused about what exactly it's doing. I'm gonna have to set up a testing environment to really understand how it is being used and passed, I think. Most of those sanitizers/filters wouldn't matter with the stuff I am trying to do, but they sure make it confusing.

Comment: lol. I hope you have or get the power to change that. Fyi: `serialize`=> `filter_var` => `unserialize` could pose another unrelated security risk. PHP serialization format can be manipulated when the lengths of strings change.